# Nuxt.js returns undefined for custom plugin

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I wanted to create a custom plugin for a local databaase in Nuxt.js, after I was done with the code I registered it in nuxt.config.js and it didn't work. So I've tried the example code on docs to see what I was doing wrong, and the thing is, example code didn't work too. Here is how I registered it:

> plugins/hello.js

```
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject("hello", msg => console.log(`Hello ${msg}!`));
};
```

> nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  ssr: false,
  target: "static",
  head: {
    title: "project-title",
    meta: [{ charset: "utf-8" }],
  },
  loading: false,
  plugins: [{ ssr: true, src: "@/plugins/icons.js" }, "@/plugins/hello.js"],
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/axios", "@nuxtjs/auth-next"],
}
```

Whenever I try to use `this.$hello("something")`, Nuxt returns [this.$hello is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h72Q8.png)

Comment: Which version of Nuxt are you using, and where are you calling `this.$hello()`? If I create a new static Nuxt project at v2.15.8, add your plugin, and modify the supplied tutorial component to add a `mounted()` function containing `this.$hello('there');` then I see logged to the console `Hello there!`

Comment: I'm using 2.15.6 and I'm calling it in a components mounted function.

Comment: Please accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, got it. After deleting and reinstalling node_modules it's resolved, then I tried changing the name of the plugin file, after then build failed from `./node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js`. After reinstalling packages *again* (deleted .nuxt, node_modules and lock file) issue is resolved.